# Unable to debug dll when unit testing - not hitting breakpoints and unable to change configuration in properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, debugging, dll

Created a library and performing some unit test. One of the Test Methods failed and I am unable to debug the issue as any break points on the dll project fail to hit.

I have tried some of the solutions on stackoverflow unsuccessfully and I was trying https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-from-a-dll-project?view=vs-2019

I have tried out both methods - "Specify a calling app in the native dll project" & "Specify a calling app in the managed dll project". But these options either do not exist or grayed out (see images).
[image]

[image]

How do I debug the DLL (add breakpoints) so I can debug the dll if it fails a Unit Test.

Comment: Wait, so are you executing the DLL or running the Unit Test Project?

Comment: I am running the Unit Test Project as I cannot run the DLL directly. Sorry I am new to unit testing and DLL (this is my first dll project)

Comment: What happens when you right click on your Unit Test project and then click on "Debug Unit Tests"?

Comment: The only option I have Debug > Start new instance. When I click that, nothing happens. Doesnt even hit the breakpoint I have on test method and neither the one in the dll.

Comment: I don't mean the tool bar at the top. Right click on the Project in your Solution explorer and you should see [these](https://i.imgur.com/1NKum9f.png) three options. Click on "Debug Tests"

Comment: Thats exactly what I did (right click on Unit Test Project in solution explorer) and I did not find any of those options.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195839/discussion-between-mindswipe-and-bandook).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Just hitting 'Run' tests doesnt hit any breakpoints in the dll. To debug dll go to Test > Debug > All Tests or hit Ctrl+R, Ctrl+A.